# Bringing back a List based on Priority

Tags: sql, arrays, sorting

I have to check that a customer id is displayed for an account where there may be multiple customers related to that account. I have to display only one customer Id based on the following priority.

1. If customer name - a.. then 1
2. If customer name - b.. then 2
3. If customer name - c.. then 3

   ```
   Case customerid
   when customer name like 'a%' then customer_id1
   when customer name like 'b%' then customer_id2
   when customer name like 'c%' then customer_id3
   else customer_id4
   end
   ```

Not sure how to write the select statement so that only the top priority id will display

```
Sample Data
    CustomerName CustomerID AccountID
    Arthur       123        acc1
    Bruce        456        acc1
    Billy        812        acc2
    Camilla      768        acc3
    Dominic      891        acc2

Expected Output
    AccountID CustomerID
    acc1      123
    acc2      812
    acc3      768
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT CUSTOMERID, ACCOUNTID
FROM
(SELECT CUSTOMERNAME, ACCOUNTID,
        RANK() OVER(GROUP BY ACCOUNTID ORDER BY 
                     CASE WHEN CUSTOMERNAME like 'a%' then 1
                          WHEN CUSTOMERNAME like 'a%' then 2
                          WHEN CUSTOMERNAME like 'a%' then 3
                      ELSE 4) RNK
 FROM TABLE1)
WHERE RNK = 1

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if I understand your question.

But according to your example your could try this:

```
SELECT AccountID, min(CustomerID)
FROM SampleData
GROUP BY AccountID
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the customer id I want should not be based one the minimum but rather going by the customers name in order of the priority.

I.e If Customer name begins with a then take that customers id else take the id of customer name begining with b.